# How to perform these ornaments?

Tags: theory, ornaments

[image: ornaments]

How do you play the "opppsite" acciaccatura?
And what does it mean by Glissafter?

Comment: Don't understand why some have an explanation, but not all.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be from the manual of a piece of software written for one individual musician to use.

I suggest you contact the author to find out what some of these non-standard terms are supposed to mean. His contact details are in https://mellowood.ca/mma/online-docs/ref/node1.html#SECTION00110000000000000000

To quote that page:

> This manual most likely has lots of errors. Spelling, grammar, and
>   probably a number of the examples need fixing

I don't think we can second-guess what he intended to mean here.